# What's state_size of a MultiRNNCell in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

With the config as below for a `BasicLSTM` cell:

```
...
num_layers = 2 
num_steps = 10 
hidden_size = 200    
...
```

I use 2-hidden layers model:

```
lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size, forget_bias=0.0) 
cell = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * 2)
```

What is the `cell.state_size`?

I got it as 30 x 800, but I can't understand how it comes to?

PS: refer to the source code in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/97f585d506cccc57dc98f234f4d5fcd824dd3c03/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L353

It seems to return `statesize` as `2 * unitsize`. But why should the state size be twice of the unit size?

Answer (score 12):

For a single `BasicLSTMCell`, the state is a tuple of `(c=200, h=200)`, in your case. `c` is the cell state of 200 units (neurons) and `h` is the hidden state of 200 units.

To understand this, consider a vanilla RNN cell. It only has one hidden state being passed from one-time step to the next. This is the case for `BasicRNNCell` implemented in TensorFlow. Its state is a single integer of h=200 if you do `tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(200)`.

LSTM adds an extra cell layer for longitudinal memory with the size same as the hidden layer, so the overall state for LSTM is 2x200 = 400.

The introduction part of [this paper](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/RNN13.pdf) might be conducive.

---

*Have to say the doc of TensorFlow is a bit too concise for beginners.*

Answer (score 7):

To compute an LSTM step you need to apply *four* functions each with dimension  `hidden_size`:

- input gate
- output gate
- forget gate
- hidden state

so you need `hidden_size * 4 = 200 * 4 = 800`

the `30` comes from your batch size, as you are processing 30 samples per batch.

and that is your cell memory consumption `(30, 800)`

See [Colah's blog post](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) that explains these operations in more detail.

Comment: Thanks @fabrizioM!  But the lstm_cell.state_size =400. I think the state_size matters the total RNN-layer number, not only the three gates and one state as u mentioned above?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this 
http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html

The lstm has two outputs , C_t (state) and h_t (hidden) and these are returned in state. The output o_t is a function of (h_(t-1),C_t,x_t) which is the output that is used for classification
output_t, [C_t,h_t] = tf.rnn.rnn(...)